# Calculating edge lengths of a tetrahedron based on constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

Given a tetrahedron $\Delta$ with unspecified vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$, but numerically specified edge lengths $h_{12}, h_{23}, h_{31}, h_{14}, h_{24}, h_{34}$, which create the constraints

$h_{12} = |v1 - v2| \\
h_{23} = |v2 - v3| \\
h_{31} = |v3 - v1| \\
h_{14} = |v1 - v4| \\
h_{24} = |v2 - v4| \\
h_{34} = |v3 - v4|$

Now if I change one of the specified $h$ values, let's say $h_{24}$ then how can I calculate the other $h$ values, namely $h_{14}$ and $h_{34}$ in this example?

Comment: You can't. The six edge lengths of a tetrahedron are independent, just like the three edge lengths of a triangle.

Comment: @Rahul They are not independent if you rigidly fixed the distance between the vertices.

Comment: The edge lengths *are* the distances between the vertices, so I don't understand what you mean. You can fix the distance between five pairs of vertices (i.e. five edge lengths) and you still have freedom to change the distance of the last pair (i.e. the remaining edge length).

Comment: At that point what you have is two rigid triangles connected by a hinge, but you can still rotate the hinge freely.

Comment: By changing one h you get a new tetrahedron.

Comment: Under certain conditions you can even change two and maintain the other 4